# Android doesn't show ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I'm trying to show a ProgressDialog when loading an Activity, but it doesn't show up.

Here is the method called on Activity *onCreate*

```
  private void loadBuilding(String[] b) {

        ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setMax(6);

        pd.setTitle(R.string.loading);

        pd.show();

        LoadBuilding lb = new LoadBuilding();
        lb.initialize(this,  pd);

        lb.execute(b);

        try {
              lb.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        pd.dismiss();

        if (building == null) 
              showError();
  }
```

The *LoadBuilding* is an *AsyncTask* in which I load the building and set the progress.

Thanks to all.

Comment: try to remove `pd.dismiss()` and all lines after it from your code and put it inside the onPostExecute method of the async task. I think that your dialog is actually shown, but it is closed very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that the **progressDialog.dismiss()** must be in:

- The **catch** of the try/catch showed in the code
- The **onPostExecute** method of AsyncTask.

Also I'm using too few data for testing, so it comes up and down too fast.

Answer (score 0):

### Use AsyncTask for Background processing and Updating Progressing in Foreground. I think that best suited your task.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```

Try to add your progressDismiss() in try and catch block

```
try
 {
   pg.dismiss();
  }
Catch()
{
 }
```